# find missing numbers in series using python

Tags: python

I have a file with numbers and I need to find the missing ones.

```
cat head.txt
7045000000
7045000001
7045000003
```

As you can see the number 7045000002 is missing. This code is not working:

```
check=int(7044999999)
with open('head.txt' , 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        myl = line[:5]
        if myl == '70450':
            if int(line) == check+1:
                check = int(line)
            else:
                check = int(line)+1
                print check
```

The numbers should start with 70450 and there the "myl" variable is necessary.

Comment: In what way isn't the code working?

Comment: What is check+1 supposed to do?

Comment: @AdamHughes I think it's just a counter; it sees if the current line matches the counter (`check`) plus 1. If it does, it means there wasn't a 'jump' in numbers. At least, that's what I think it means.

Comment: Are the numbers guaranteed to be in increasing order?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the logic;

```
for i in range(7045000000,9045000000):
    if i not in line:
        print ("{} is missing".format(i))
```

Just use the basics of `for` loop. `9045000000` is a casual number. I don't know your database actually, so you can(should) change the last number in `range()` function.

**Here is a demo**;

```
with open("coz.txt") as f:
    rd=f.readlines()
    x=[t.strip("\n") for t in rd]
    for i in range(7045000000,7045000004):
        if str(i) not in x:
            print ("{} is missing".format(i))
```

Output;

```
>>> 
7045000002 is missing
>>>
```

And this is the .txt file that I tried these codes;

[image]

Comment: But since the first line is `7045000000`, this will immediately say "7045000001 is missing", which is false (it's the second line!).  {I didn't downvote, just pointing out the glaring bug).

Comment: If you have enough memory to read everything in at once (rather than going by line as the first snippet suggests by its variable names) your latest code will work, but not as efficiently as `set`s would.

Comment: Yes. set seems to be much faster. I have benchmark tests to prove. I can not post the answer here because the question is now closed as duplicate.